# New Tab Extension for Edge Against Polcy

Tags: microsoft-edge, browser-extension, microsoft-edge-extension

Is developing an Extension for Microsoft Edge, that customizes (or replaces) the new tab page against Microsoft's policy? This appears to be the case, but I am not sure if I am interpreting it correctly.

I would like to develop a custom new tab, as is frequently seen with Chrome ([example](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/infinite-new-tab-the-best/meffljleomgifbbcffejnmhjagncfpbd)) and Firefox ([example](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/infinity-new-tab-pro-firefox/?src=search)), but this appears to not be possible.

Policy linked [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/windows/agreements/microsoft-browser-extension-policy#modification-of-microsoft-edge-settings).

Comment: I understand the situation. However as your Extension will be breaking the Edge Extension Store policy(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/windows/agreements/store-policies#1012-edge-extensions) you wont be able to publish the Extension in MS Store. However you can distribute the Extension through other channels (Example: Your website etc)

Answer (score 0):

Below are the requirements for Edge Extensions.

Your Extension must have a single purpose with narrowly scoped       functionality that is clearly explained in the product description.

Your Extension may collect personal information only as part of a       prominently disclosed, user-facing feature.

If your Extension    collects web browsing activity, it must do so    only if required by and    only for use in a prominently disclosed,    user-facing feature.

The Extension must not programmatically alter,    or appear to alter, browser functionality or settings including, but    not limited to: the address bar search provider and suggestions, the    start or home page, the new tab page, and adding or removing    favorites and reading list items.

Reference:

[Microsoft Store Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/windows/agreements/store-policies#1012-edge-extensions)

So as per the documentation, you can develop an extension for a Tab. at the time of hosting the extension, store will check the extension and raise the error if your extension violates any policy.

You can review the policies from above link and then try to correct it and again host your extension.